# Google places API - popular times

Tags: google-places-api

Does anybody know if Google expose the new 'Popular times' information in the places API? and if not is there another API I can use to get a locations popularity?

Comment: AFAIK Google doesn't expose this information through any API today. I suggest filing a feature request [here](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/entry?template=Places%20API%20-%20Feature%20Request).

Comment: There are plenty of feature requests on this over at Google Maps API tracker. (most marked as duplicate of https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=8581 )

Answer (score 21):

As of now (2016-12-15), no, as can be found at https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details#PlaceDetailsResults.
There's no other API for that information. You could use the API ratings return to do something alike, but still not the same.

You can track the existing requests for the feature (and star & bump it) at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35827350.

Comment: Is this still not exposed?

Comment: How about now? Is it exposed?

Comment: Still not exposed :'(