# Is it possible to get the "Popular times" information through the Google Places API

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api, google-places-api

Is it possible to get the "Popular times" information through the Google Places API or any other API? I need this information to be displayed in my application for a particular place.

Comment: Also here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32462853/google-places-api-popular-times

Comment: @ashwin - Have found any way to implement this using javascript/jquery ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't managed to test it myself but this is what `populartimes` offers to do in Python:

```
import populartimes
populartimes.get("your-api-key", ["bar"], (48.132986, 11.566126), (48.142199, 11.580047))
```

More info on developer's [github](https://github.com/m-wrzr/populartimes).

Comment: Be careful with this solution as it might be against of ToS paragraph 10.1 (a)

Comment: @radek Can you please guide me to implement this same in my MVC application (using javascript/jquey)?

Comment: There is [an anecdote](https://github.com/m-wrzr/populartimes/issues/90#issuecomment-664045321) of somebodies account being suspended for this.

Answer (score 18):

This is one of the top feature requests in Google issue tracker (more than 500 stars):

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35827350

Currently, the state is Assigned, however, no any ETA provided by Google. Please star it to get further updates.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to scrape it, but it violates the Google ToS.

Comment: @radek Section 10.1 (a) of ToS: "**No access to APIs or Content except through the Service.** You will not access the Maps API(s) or the Content except through the Service. For example, you must not access map tiles or imagery through interfaces or channels (including undocumented Google interfaces) other than the Maps API(s)." https://developers.google.com/maps/terms?#section_10_1

Comment: Thank you @xomena!

Comment: In practice, what does violating the Google ToS actually mean if you do it? Will they ban your account? Will they take legal action against you?

Answer (score 0):

yes its possible but as said it violates googles ToS ,
i have used npm package busy-hours but it's not working so i have modified their code and here is new npm package 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-busy-hours