# Number of Visitors by Hour

Tags: web-services, google-places-api

Is there a way to obtain from the Google Map API, the number of visitors to a place by hour of the year? I saw that I could get information like reviews and price level for a place, but not the number of visitors per hour. Essentially, I want to get the detailed data behind the Popular Times graph shown in Google Maps

Comment: Short answer is, no, that feature is not available to any Google Maps API services, however, there is an existing feature request here which you can star the issue to get notifications:  https://issuetracker.google.com/35827350

Comment: This is the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32462853